# How to use dynamic localization keys with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization, swiftui

I'm trying to display a localized text based on an ID. I have a lot of these, so it feels more efficient to just add dynamically the ID to the string.

The string file looks like this:

```
"users.1.name" = "Alice"
"users.2.name" = "Bob"
"users.3.name" = "Charles"
...
```

If I do the following, hardcoding the ID, it works as expected and displays the associated translated key:

`Text("users.1.name")`

However if I do this it only displays the string:

```
Text("users.\(user.id).name")
// displays "users.1.name" instead of "Alice"
```

I've also tried:

```
Text(LocalizedStringKey("users.\(user.id).name"))
// displays "users.1.name" instead of "Alice"
```

Am I missing something or is this not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need then the following. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

```
Text(NSLocalizedString("users.\(id).name", comment: ""))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this doesn't answer my question. I'm not looking to show the ID, but to create a dynamic localization id. I've edited my question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a SwiftUI expert but you can use:

```
let key:String = "users.\(user.id).name"
Text(LocalizedStringKey(key))

// OR compact

Text(LocalizedStringKey(String("users.\(user.id).name")))
```