# swiftui localization of dynamic string from database

Tags: xcode, swiftui, localization, xcode13

I'm localizing my app in swiftui using the Xcode auto generating localized string but I'm facing with a problem on how to localize a string that came from a database in my case Firestone

[image: view string]

as is possible to see in the picture I have the description that point to the data downloaded from the database and in the database the string could be one of the option in the comment. I have try to add LocalizedStringKey method but how can I translate all the string?

thanks for your help

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63470575/12299030?

Comment: unfortunately not, because it don't solve that question too

Comment: The question is not clear, what do you mean by "all the string" - elaborate more on question details and provide minimal reproducible example or your code showing what do you want to achieve.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI localization doesn't work shows only keys Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70879475/swiftui-localization-doesnt-work-shows-only-keys-xcode)

Comment: The comment is used by automatic generation of localised strings files. In your case, as the value comes from database the generator may not work. You have to create/add/update localised string file with all the strings that may comes from your db and may be displayed to the user.

Comment: yes thanks, I have done in this ways